# Any Step By Step Guides to Updating Smarty PHP Framework?

Tags: php, smarty, hhvm

Trying to fathom out how to update smarty php framework from 3.11 to current 3.21

Can anyone suggest where to find a detailed guide for a dummy or list step by step here?
Ive searched just about everywhere.

Yes i understand 3.22 arrives shortly (2 weeks) and will come as standard set for HHVM this being why i want to resolve any issues now in the current update before tackling any when 3.22 arrives.

Thanks

Comment: The new version should have upgrade instructions in the release notes, I would expect?

Comment: Hi there Halfer, no.

Answer (score 1):

Updating Smarty from version `3.xx` to `3.yy` is usually not very difficult, its nothing like the big upgrade from `2.xx` (but they've [written a guide](http://smarty-php.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/distribution/SMARTY_2_BC_NOTES.txt) for that....). Just replace your Smarty installation directory with the one from of the newer installation.

Just for safety reasons, I usually do it like this in my development enviroments.

Directory structure:

```
./Smarty/     <- Symlink to ./Smarty-3.1.12/
./Smarty-3.1.12/
./Smarty-3.1.13/
```

Your php-scripts include Smarty like this:

```
require('./Smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php');
```

For an update just copy the newer version into a new folder and change the symlink to show to the new folder.

```
rm Smarty 
ln -s Smarty-3.1.13 Smarty
```

If you run into issues, just switch the symlink back to the old installation until solving the issues.

You might have to empty your `/templates_c/`-directory, too, in some cases.